# error: class, interface, or enum expected Bubble Sort

Tags: java, sorting, enums, interface

Im currently lost as to what the problem is with the below code.  The objective of the program is to sort the listed items using a bubble sort.

```
import java.util.Scanner;                               //Library for scanner input

class JavaAssignmentTwo{                                //Start of java program

    public static void main(String args[]){             //Main section of the program
      int item;                                         //loop variable 

      String prodname[] = 
      {"Coke", "Red Bull", "7Up", "Water", "Fanta", "Sprite", "Tayto Crisps"};  //Products for sale


      System.out.print("\t\t    Sorting Carrefour Stock.");             
      System.out.print("\n\t  ---------------------------\n\n");    
      System.out.print("\n\tOriginal order\n\n");
      for (item = 0; item<prodname.length; item++){
        System.out.printf("%-3d%-15s\n",(item+1),prodname[item]);   
      } 
      System.out.print("\n\n\tSorted order\n\n");
      Easy_Sort_routines.Bubble_sort(prodname, true);

      Easy_Sort_routine.display_array(prodname);

    }

}
// --------------------------------------------------------------
// BUBBLE SORT for an array of strings
// asds = true => ascending
public static void Bubble_sort(String ss[], boolean asds){
  int zzz, jjj;
  String temp = "";

  for (jjj=0; jjj<ss.length; jjj++){
    for (zzz=1; zzz<ss.length; zzz++){
      if (asds){
        if (ss[zzz-1].compareTo(ss[zzz]) >0){    // ascending
          temp = ss[zzz-1];       // swap elements
          ss[zzz-1] = ss[zzz];
          ss[zzz] = temp;
        }
        else
          if (ss[zzz].compareTo(ss[zzz]) <0){    // descending
            temp = ss[zzz-1];       // swap elements
            ss[zzz-1] = ss[zzz];
            ss[zzz] = temp;
          }                    // end of descending if
        }   
      }      // end of zzz loop
  }       // end of jjj loop
}         // end of Bub_sort

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Display array routine

public static void display_array(String ss[]){
 int index;

 for (index = 0; index<ss.length; index++){
  System.out.printf("%-3d%-15s\n",(index+1),ss[index]);
    }
  }
}
```

The error I am running into is error: class, interface, or enum expected.  I'm still pretty new to java and I'm unaware what is causing this problem?  If anybody could point me in the right direction please.

Comment: Please read [ask] and add the complete stacktrace.

Comment: Which line? Where do you get it?

Comment: The most obvious problem is the indentation. Fixing that will make fixing anything else easier.

Comment: Console is showing the error from lines 36-67 which is just my sorting section and the display array.  Sorry I should have said that.

Comment: Indenting shows the mistake: *You are declaring methods outside of the class* ...

Comment: I think you have an extraneous bracket two lines up from `// BUBBLE SORT for an array of strings`.

Answer (score 0):

See comment in this snippet:

```
      // ...
      Easy_Sort_routine.display_array(prodname);

    }

} // <=== Remove this! It closes your class body.
// --------------------------------------------------------------
// BUBBLE SORT for an array of strings
```

Comment: Thanks guys I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: @TrevorCooke You missed it because your indentation was screwed up. Lesson.